# passing space in the value of textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox which is dynamically being added as

```
<div id="main"></div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    var time = '2014-04-20 00:00:00';
    var textbox = = '<input type="text" id="timeStatus" value='+time+'>';
    $('#main').html(textbox);
});
```

However, the value after the space `00:00:00` is not displayed.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your HTML code ends upp looking like this:

```
<input type="text" id="timeStatus" value=2014-04-20 00:00:00>
```

As you don't have any quotation marks around the value for the `value` attribute, only the part before the space will be used as the value, the rest will be a separate (invalid) attribute.

You should add quotation marks so that the HTML code ends up like this:

```
<input type="text" id="timeStatus" value="2014-04-20 00:00:00">
```

That would be:

```
var textbox = '<input type="text" id="timeStatus" value="'+time+'">';
```